# isometric tilemap and retina display in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I made a game with isometric tilemap in cocos2d and it works good on non-retina ipad (collision detection and so on), but when I run it on retina ipad, everything is messed up. Is it possible to make it retina compatible without creating new tmx file and making new calculations? I'm having problems in my positionForIsoMapAt method which looks like  this:

```
 -(CGPoint) positionForIsoAt:(CGPoint)pos
{
    CGPoint xy = {
        _mapTileSize.width /2 * ( _layerSize.width + pos.x - pos.y - 1),
        _mapTileSize.height /2 * (( _layerSize.height * 2 - pos.x - pos.y) - 2),
    };
    return xy;
}
```

It's not returning correct coordinates on retina (non retina works good)

Answer (score 0):

TMX maps work based on pixels, iOS is point-based.  Make sure that you are not loading the atlas images with @2x which loads the images in points.  Also make sure the position passed in is calculated correctly in pixels as well.